# Parallel.ForEach returning inconsistent result

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a method which reads a text file which contains an int value per line, for making reading faster, i used `Parallel.ForEach`, but the behaviour what i am seeing is unexpected, i have 800 lines in the file but when i run this method, every time it returns different count of HashSet, what i have read after searching is `Parallel.ForEach` spawns multiple threads and it returns the result when all threads have completed their work, but my code execute contradicts, or i am missing something improtant here?

Here is my method:

```
private HashSet<int> GetKeyItemsProcessed()
{
   HashSet<int> keyItems = new HashSet<int>();

   if (!File.Exists(TrackingFilePath))
     return keyItems;

     // normal foreach works fine

     //foreach(var keyItem in File.ReadAllLines(TrackingFilePath))
     //{
     //    keyItems.Add(int.Parse(keyItem));
     //}


     // this does not return right number of hashset rows
     Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadAllLines(TrackingFilePath).AsParallel(), keyItem =>
     {
         keyItems.Add(int.Parse(keyItem));
     });


    return keyItems;

}
```

Comment: I can bet this is not `C`.

Comment: Modifying a `HashSet` [is not-thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_10). Why don't you use one of the Concurent collections like ConcurrenDictionary or ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: i am using `HashSet<T>` for better performance, are the above you mentioned are performant when reading from them?

Comment: HashSet modification is *not* faster than other collections. It's faster in set operations. In this case, it simply can't be used. If you really want to use the result for set operations, you can create a HashSet from the original collection, with the constructor that accepts an IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Your bottleneck would almost definitely be disk-bound, not CPU bound. So, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to run it in parallel. Further, unless you're using it for a *lookup*, a `List` is probably better (it's unclear what you mean by 'reading' from the collection)

Comment: Your `.AsParallel()` is just causing extra overhead and is not giving you any benefit, `Parallel.ForEach` does not support a parallel enumerable so it will just be serialized again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashSet.Add` is NOT thread safe.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

The unpredictability of multithread timing could, and seems to be, causing issues.

You could wrap the access in a synchronization construct, which is sometimes faster than a concurrent collection, but may not speed anything up in some cases.  As others have mentioned, another option is to use a thread safe collection like `ConcurrenDictionary` or `ConcurrentQueue`, though those may have additional memory overhead.

Be sure to benchmark any results you get with regards to timing. The raw power of singlethreaded access can sometimes be faster than dealing with the overhead of threading.  It may not be worth it at all to thread this code.

The final word though, is that `HashSet` alone, without synchronization, is simply unacceptable for multi threaded operations.

Comment: A `lock` over a synchronous collection can be faster than using a concurrent collection. It depends on the level of contention. In fact, we should go one step further: `Parallel.ForEach` isn't necessarily faster at all in the OP's scenario. Simply reading the lines sequentially can easily win out over the parallel overhead. (Of course, this goes beyond the scope of the original question, which simply asks why the result is inconsistent.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert in Disk I/O parallelism won't help if file is too large?

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary worked well but i think if in Disk I/O it would be overhead instead of performing better then i won't go with Parallel loop

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: [Why are you asking me?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @JeroenMostert because you said that, so confirming if you tested that

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: sorry, let me be more clear, I meant: follow the link to learn why you shouldn't be asking strangers on the internet what's faster (and even if they volunteer to tell you, don't just believe them). My statement is entirely based on my intuition. Even if I told you I tested it, why would you believe me? You're much better off testing it yourself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i never thought i am talking to a stranger, we are a community and all are like family here, so if someone has already done some research, why other also put time and effort doing same thing again,